# Google Calender API - Get eventID In a Calender

Tags: google-calendar-api

I need to get eventID's of a Calendar. I list events and some information about them but i can not get their ID's. I used this doc: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list

```
// Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
$calendarId = 'xxxx@group.calendar.google.com';
$optParams = array(
  'maxResults' => 100,
  'orderBy' => 'startTime',
  'singleEvents' => true,
  'timeMin' => date('c', strtotime("monday -1 week")),
  'timeMax' => date('c'),
  
  
  
);
$results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
$events = $results->getItems();

if (empty($events)) {
    print "No upcoming events found.\n";
} else {
    //print "Upcoming events:\n";
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $start = $event->start->dateTime;
        if (empty($start)) {
            $start = $event->start->date;
        }
        printf("%s %s\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [events.list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)

Returns a response

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#events",
  "etag": etag,
  "summary": string,
  "description": string,
  "updated": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "accessRole": string,
  "defaultReminders": [
    {
      "method": string,
      "minutes": integer
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "nextSyncToken": string,
  "items": [
    events Resource
  ]
}
```

Which contains a list of [Event Resources](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource)

An event resource has a field called id.

```
{
  "kind": "calendar#event",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": string,
  ....
```

So depending upon which language you would be using it would just be a matter of looping though each of the items returned by the method and then accessing the id of that event.

C# example.

```
 foreach(var event in response.Items){

    Console.WriteLine(event.Id)
  }
```